# Dimension of the global sections of the Serre twisting sheaf on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let, $C$ be a projective curve (not necessarily reduced), $i:C \to \mathbb{P}^n$ be a closed immersion. Does there exist a bound on/geometric interpretation of the dimension of $H^0(i^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking about $i^\ast \mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ as $\mathcal O_C(1)$, there is a natural exact sequence

$$0 \to I_C(1) \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1) \to \mathcal O_C(1) \to 0.$$

Assuming $C$ is non-degenerate, we obtain an exact sequence in cohomology

$$0\to H^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))\to H^0(\mathcal O_C(1))\to H^1( I_C(1))\to 0.$$

It folllows that $h^0(\mathcal O_C(1))\geq n+1$, with equality if and only if the $H^1$ group above vanishes.  The vanishing of this $H^1$ is called *linear normality* of the embedded curve.  There are several different properties which are equivalent to linear normality of an embedded curve, some of which are more or less geometric:

(1) Hyperplanes cut a complete linear series on $C$.

(2) $C$ is embedded by a complete linear series.

(3) $C$ is not a projection of a non-degenerate embedding from a higher-dimensional projective space.

(4) $H^1(I_C(1))=0$

In practice, the fourth property is usually the most useful for attempting to show a curve is linearly normal, as you can compute this cohomology group via other methods, such as resolving the ideal sheaf.

Comment: Just to explicate, linearly normal means that the embedding is not the projection of an embedding in a bigger projective space. I think most people would view that as the geometric explanation.

Comment: @Huizenga: Could you give an example of linearly normal curve?

Comment: @agniesky: Yes, I suppose that is a more satisfactory geometric condition.  Edited.

Comment: @Chen: As the edit now says, a curve is linearly normal iff it is embedded by a complete linear series.

Comment: @Huizenga: Another small question. I am not able to find a good reference for non-degenrate curve. Does it mean that the curve is not contained in a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: Yes.  Arborello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris "Geometry of Algebraic Curves" is the standard reference for these things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11404/discussion-between-chen-and-jack-huizenga)